# Loading modules Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to load a module only when I have an internet connection. The problem is that I dont know how to proceed. The module that I'm trying to load is the ngMap, and here is the code that I am using, but it is not working:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova','starter.getters','starter.main','starter.intro'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.Connection) {
                if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                    $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: "Ligação à internet",
                        content: "Por favor ligue-se a internet para fazer uso de todas as funcionalidades."
                    })
                    .then(function(result) {
                        if(!result) {
                            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                        }
                    });
                }
          else
          {
              //the module I'm trying to load when I do have internet
               angular.module('starter', ['ngMap']);

                // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
                // for form inputs)
                if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
                }
                if(window.StatusBar) {
                  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                  StatusBar.styleDefault();
                }
          }

      }
      })

  })
```

I tried loading the module in the main module declaration, but it gave me an error saying that it was unable to load the module.

How can I proceed in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure loading the module conditionally is the way to go.  Load the module all the time but only use it in your controller if you have access to the internet.

Comment: Do you have the `script` tags to pull in the ngMap javascript files?

Comment: @ChrisStory The problem is that if I load the module everytime, I get this error:
ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 

I don't know how to circumvent that...

Comment: @Malkus yes, it is defined in the index.html file. The problem is that the module isn't always available, since everytime that I open the app, the script is downloaded again. I need some kind of workaround for when there is no internet..

Comment: If you are trying to make an app that won't always have internet access, then you should not use CDN or be downloading scripts from the internet on run time.  You should download the package or script and place it in your application that way.

Comment: Simple as that if you want that scritp file offline then download and put in ionic lib folder.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani , @ ChrisStory, thanks for the suggestions. Seems that I was trying to overcomplicate, so I ended up following your suggestions and I putted the script locally, solving the problem. Can't believe I didn't thought of that sooner...